# Blank excel spreadsheet when unzipping file

Tags: excel, unzip, zip, gzip

I'm researching a project on software defined networking discussed on knowledgedefinednetworking.org and they provide several datasets. Two of the three datasets are unzipping just fine (100K.csk.gz & train.csv.gz), but benchmark.csv.gz unzips into a new spreadsheet but still uses 3.3GB of memory. I'm using WinZip to unzip the files and they're all going into the same folder, but only benchmark is coming back empty. Is this a common issue or is there something potentially wrong with the download of the file that causes it to unzip empty?

Comment: SO is for questions directly related to programming - this question is better-suited to a different forum.  Or try contacting the source of the files to ask for help?

Comment: "new spreadsheet but still uses 3.3GB of memory" <-- that's normal. | "something potentially wrong with the download of the file that causes it to unzip empty?"<-- just open the csv with notepad++ or other software to test. If all fail, refer to the source. (:

Answer (score 0):

"Is this a common issue"  <-- Simple answer : Yes, it is a coomn issue.

"or is there something potentially wrong with the download of the file that causes it to unzip empty?"  <-- the download went ok.. I tried to save it as excel. went ok. The files ([file1](https://utpmy-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/mohammad_g03606_utp_edu_my/Eb2vX4lLrTBLrRqDCF_J4yYBatnARh52vrCyAPN0mTTElw?e=CCUFwt) [file2](https://utpmy-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/mohammad_g03606_utp_edu_my/ETrnMVOtM4tPlcSIsVVuqHgBzDZouZ9aSF8P-y_siYMYWA?e=eE2W3C)) is not blank.

Note : try to use 7zip as your file uncompressor.

Hope that solves... (: